# AngularJS: force DOM update during long-running loop (i.e. progress indicator)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app allows a user to supply data for analysis, and I would like to provide a progress indicator. Although my model correctly reflects the progress, the DOM is only updated upon conclusion of the analysis (and hence conclusion of the digest loop). Is there a way that I can force rendering mid-digest?

I realise that my other option is to extract the analysis such that it runs independently of the digest loop and then call $scope.$apply, but this refactoring is undesirable.

```
<div>{{progress}}</div>
<script>
  ...
  for(i=0; i<dataPoints.length; i++){
    ...long-running analysis inside the digest loop...
    $scope.progress = (i+1)/dataPoints.length * 100;
    //how do I force a DOM update here?
  }
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: You could wrap it in a $timeout as well. Or you could as well use $q and use promise pattern and use notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you take the loop outside of the digest as long as it's part of the main thread and remains synchronous it won't update the DOM until it finishes.

Your options are:

1. Set the each element analysis to be performed in a timeout function and update your progress from there. This is good if you don't care in what order the operations are finished, something like

   ```
   for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
       $timeout(function(){
           //do something here and increase the progress counter
       })
   }
   ```
2. If you care about the order, use recursive functions something like

   ```
   function recursive(arr, index){
       if(arr.length==index-1){
           //you are done
       }
       //do something
       $timeout(function(){
           recursive(arr,index+1)
       })
   }
   ```
3. If you don't care about old browsers, use webworker.  This is a more complex solution; you can see it at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).

Comment: Thank you. Although I had to specify a timeout of at least a few milliseconds as 0 seems to execute within the same digest.

Comment: it doesn't , timeout(0) defers the execution to the next cycle,  but it might happen that if your processing is too extensive could prevent the threat from update properly, so specifying some ms would give some time for those tasks to clear. glad it solved your problem